# category and Brand both seach at a time in php

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

i am creating a e-commerce website. Example if i click category as Tv and brand as LG the relevant product should display.but it is not working well.no error diplayed
what I tried so far i have written below.

**Form Design**

**Category**

```
<div align="left">
  <li class="list-group-item list-group-item-action active" > 
   <h4>Category</h4></li>
 <li class="list-group-item list-group-item-action" id="categories"></li>
  </div>
```

**Brand**

```
<div align="left" >
    <li class="list-group-item list-group-item-action active" ><h4>Brand</h4></li>
        <li class="list-group-item list-group-item-action" id="brands"></li>
</div>
```

**Products**

```
   <div class="panel-heading">
                Products
            </div>
            <div class="panel-body" id="Products" >

            </div>
```

**jquery**

**Category**

```
 function getCategory(){
        $.ajax({
            type: 'GET',
            url: 'get_category.php' ,
            dataType: 'JSON',
            success: function (data)
            {
                for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++)
                {
                    var catname = data[i].catname;
                    var id = data[i].id;
                    $('#categories').append('<a href="#" cid= '+ id + '  class="list-group-item list-group-item-action">' + '<b>'+ data[i].catname + '<b>' + '</a>');
                }
            },
            error: function (xhr, status, error)
               {
                console.log(xhr.message)
            }

        });
    }
```

**Brand**

```
   function getBrand(){
        $.ajax({
            type: 'GET',
            url: 'all_brand.php' ,
            dataType: 'JSON',
            success: function (data) {
                console.log(data);
                for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++)
                {
                    var id1 = data[i].id;
                    $('#brands').append('<a href="#"  bid= '+ id1 + '  class="list-group-item list-group-item-action">' + '<b>'+ data[i].brand_name + '<b>' + '</li>');
                }
            },
            error: function (xhr, status, error) {
                alert(xhr.responseText);
            }
        });
    }
```

Categroy and brand diplayed succesfully.

**Product**

if i click category and brand at the time the relevant product will display. this how i wrote query

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#categories a.list-group-item").click(function () {
        var cat = $(this).attr('cid');


        var brand = $("#brands a.list-group-item").click();
        var brand = $(this).attr('bid');
        $.ajax({
            url: 'get_search.php',
            type: 'post',
           data: {cat: cat, brand: brand},
          //  data: {cat: cat},
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function (data) {
                var len = data.length;
                console.log(data);
                $("#Products").empty();
                for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                    var price = data[i].price;
                    var image = data[i].image;
                    var description = data[i].description;
                    $("#Products").append("<div class='col-md-4'> " +
                    "<div class='panel panel-info' id='Products'>" +
                    "<div class='card-body'>" +
                    "<div class='panel-heading'>" + "<h4> " + description + "</h4> " +
                    "<p class='panel-body'>" + "<h3> " + price + "</h3>" +
                    "<p class='panel-body'> <img class='card-img-top' style='width:250px' height='250px' id='theImg' src='images/" + image + "' /> </p>" +
                    " <a href='#' class='btn btn-primary'>View More</a> </div> </div></div> </div>");
                }
            }
        });
    });
});
```

**get_search.php**

```
   <?php
include("db.php");

$stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT id,cat_id,brand_id,price,description,image,keywords from products WHERE cat_id = ? AND brand_id = ? ");
$stmt->bind_result($id,$cat_id,$brand_id,$price,$description,$image,$keywords);

$cat_id = $_POST["cat"];
$brand = $_POST['brand'];
$stmt->bind_param("ss", $cat_id,$brand);
$stmt->bind_result($id,$cat_id,$brand_id,$price,$description,$image,$keywords);



if ($stmt->execute()) {
    while ( $stmt->fetch() ) {
        $output[] = array ("id"=>$id, "cat_id"=>$cat_id,"brand_id"=>$brand_id,"price"=>$price,"description"=>$description,"image"=>$image,"keywords"=>$keywords);
    }

    echo json_encode( $output );
}
$stmt->close();


?>
```

Comment: What exactly does "it is not working well" mean? Are you not getting the correct results? Are you not getting any results?

Comment: no sir. i am not getting the correct result sir.

Comment: What are you getting? What are you expecting?

Comment: if i click category as Tv and brand as LG relevant product should display. category and brand both search at a time

Comment: Your search query is looking for exact matches for both category and brand. If the columns don't have exactly the same values you won't get any results. You may want to consider using `LIKE` instead of `=` in your query. Also, check the values that are being posted to make sure they contain the values you think they do.

Comment: if you write the query it is more helpful for me sir. i have been trying this for 2 weeks

Comment: Change the `=` to `LIKE` in your query and then change `$stmt->bind_param("ss", $cat_id,$brand);` to `$stmt->bind_param("ss", '%' . $cat_id. '%','%' . $brand . '%');`

Comment: $stmt->bind_param("ss", '%' . $cat_id. '%', '%' . $brand . '%'); if i wrote like this there will be the syntax error

Comment: Nope, that should work fine.

Comment: no sir. sir shall i send my project you.can you correct the error sir. please

Comment: What I put in my comment will not create a syntax error. If you are getting an error you either didn't copy/paste it correctly or made a typo when entering it.

Comment: yes. i copied and paste it sir. it is not working sir

Comment: Please add the exact error you are getting to your original question. As I said, what I posted was verified to not create a syntax error.

Comment: $stmt->bind_param("ss", '%' . $cat_id. '%', '%' . $brand . '%');
only variable can be passed by reference . category i listed as <li> and brand i listed as <li> is there any error on that

Answer (score 1):

I knew there was a reason I disliked mysqli. Suggest you switch to using PDO and the code below will get you the results you are looking for. Building the array to return in JSON format is left for you to complete.

```
$conn = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=test;charset=utf8mb4','username','password');

$_POST["cat"]   = 'TV';
$_POST['brand'] = 'LG';

$stmt = $conn->prepare('SELECT id,description from products
                        WHERE cat_id LIKE :catid AND brand_id LIKE :brand');

$cat_id = '%' . $_POST["cat"]   . '%';
$brand  = '%' . $_POST['brand'] . '%';

$stmt->execute([':catid' => '%' . $cat_id . '%',
                ':brand' => '%' . $brand  . '%']);
$results = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
print_r($results);
```

Comment: sir my jquery having a problem cat_id and brand_id not posted to  get_search.php page but no error display can you check the query on Product query

Comment: You need to add the columns you want to the query. I only created 3 of them for testing. And, as I said, you need to create the JSON to be returned. I only got you past your query issues.

Comment: ("#categories a.list-group-item").click(function () {
        var cat = $(this).attr('cid');
    var brand = $("#brands a.list-group-item").click();
        var brand = $(this).attr('bid');   is this correct we post the value to get_search page. values are not posted